# Book for Spline interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question

I need a book or lecture notes for the course spline interpolation and has best way of explaining  with the proofs of theorems. Thank you!!!

Comment: Carl de Boor's book  "A practical guide to splines" is well known. To be honest, I personally don't like the book, but I know people who do.

Comment: I don't have a book to recommend, but rather a source code: https://github.com/chen0040/cpp-spline -- it covers Bezier curves, B-spline curves, and Catmull-Rom curves. The source is set up to show exactly how each of these three types of curves differ from each other, in terms of the math involved.

Comment: @DionelJaimeThank you !!

Comment: @shawn_halayka thank you !!

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590959

Answer (score 3):

This past spring I took a course on numerical analysis. We used $\textit{Numerical Methods}$ by Anne Greenbaum and Timothy Chartier. The sections on polynomial interpolation were quite detailed and possessed understandable proofs. I highly recommend the text. Their [website](https://academics.davidson.edu/math/chartier/Numerical/matlab.html) also contains MATLAB codes for further perusal, although I don't believe there are any uploaded for polynomial interpolation. When I had to present for that course, I did find some adaptable scripts from websites like GitHub.

Comment: Tnx i appreciate it

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if you would like additional information about the textbook.

Answer (score 2):

There is a large bibliography [here](https://github.com/bubbakittee/GeomBib): You can search it for books on splines. The well-known ones are by deBoor, Piegl & Tiller, Elber & Cohen, Hoscheck & Lasser, Farin, Gallier, and others.